# Try rebuilding a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS while the kernel 5.4.30 amd64 cannot be found in mainline

Tags: kernel

I try to build a special Ubuntu version with some drivers preinstalled. I find that **Ubuntu 20.04 desktop amd64** is using **5.4.0-26.30-generic**, and in the mainline it should be 5.4.30. But I can't find the 5.4.30 amd64 version of kernel in https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.30/

So how should I find it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu kernels and mainline kernels are different.

Answer (score 0):

UKUU indicates v5.4.28 is lated 5.4 installable on x86-64.  I looked on https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.30/ and https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.4.40/ as well, and it appears there's a build failure on i386 and amd64.  I looked at build log (look for "**" to find interesting bits) and it bails out building wireguard, building this wireguard module fails so the entire build fails rather than shipping without an expected module.  I'm using ukuu to install on Ubuntu 18.04, but I must assume with 5.4 being the standard kernel on Ubuntu 20.04, that they will fix wireguard so they can benefit from more updated 5.4 kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my reply, I looked at wireguards site, they have a patch for the exact error I saw in the logs just put in 6 days ago.  If kernel is greater than or equal to 5.4.28, it includes one more .h to avoid the build failure.